# Error in incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Tags: r, matrix, svd

I am trying to do simple parametric bootstrap on a matrix Y.

`str(Y)`

```
num [1:10, 1:7] 2333 2815 2326 3097 2813 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : chr [1:10] "A77" "A86" "C87" "C88" ...
 ..$ : chr [1:7] "CHIP" "CORS" "EVAN" "HODG" ...

B = 100000 
I = nrow(Y)
J = ncol(Y)
M = min(I-1,J-1)
D =I-1
MaxK = M-2
```

**Initiation of some matrices**

```
T <{ matrix(NA, nrow = MaxK + 1, ncol = 1)
ProbT <{ matrix(NA, nrow = MaxK + 1, ncol = 1)
Star <{ matrix(NA, nrow = M, ncol = B)
```

**Singular value decomposition**

```
RowMeans =matrix(rowMeans(Y), nrow = I, ncol = J)
ColMeans= t(matrix(colMeans(Y), nrow = J, ncol = I))
Mean = matrix(mean(Y), nrow = I, ncol = J)
E=Y-RowMeans-ColMeans+Mean
lambda = svd(E)$d ; lambda
```

**Test statistic**

```
K <- 0
while(K <= MaxK){
  Term <- K + 1
  if(K > 0) lambda[K] <- 0
  T[Term, 1] <- lambda[Term]^2/(t(lambda)%*%lambda)


boot <- 1
while(boot <= B){
Eb<-matrix(rnorm((D-K)*(J-1-K)), nrow=I-1-K, ncol=J-1-K)
lambdab <- svd(Eb)$d
Tb <-lambdab[1]^2/(t(lambdab)%*%lambdab)
      
ifelse(Tb > T[Term,1], Star[Term, boot] <- 1, Star[Term, boot] <- 0)
boot = boot + 1}
    
ProbT[Term, 1] <- rowMeans(Star)[Term]
K <- K+1}
```

But I am getting an error like this

```
Error in T[Term, 1] <- lambda[Term]^2/(t(lambda) %*% lambda) :    incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Where is the mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't show us where `T` was defined.  You can't assume R will create a matrix because you always use it as one:  you need to explicitly create it first.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I defined the `T` `ProbT`  `Star` matrices. It worked out fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Had to define the `T` `ProbT`  `Star` matrices.

```
T <{ matrix(NA, nrow = MaxK + 1, ncol = 1)
ProbT <{ matrix(NA, nrow = MaxK + 1, ncol = 1)
Star <{ matrix(NA, nrow = M, ncol = B)
```